# Delete files older than 6 months with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have to delete tmp files that are older than 6 months. I have this command runing in the batch file which delete files older than 180 days.

```
forfiles /p "C:\Backup" /s /m *.tmp /c "cmd /c Del @path" /d -180
```

but I want to pass `number of month` instead of `number of days`. any idea would be greatly helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you passing days to forfile in your batchfile now?

Comment: How critical is the 6 months period?  Is 3 or 4 days one way or the other significant?

Comment: I have mentioned the number of days directly in the batch file and just running the batch file in the task schedular

Answer (score 2):

You could also use powershell commands if you really want to provide day, month, year any of these as an argument.

Example:

```
Get-ChildItem –Path  “C:\Backups” –Recurse | Where-Object CreationTime –lt (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6) | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK for `forfiles` you cant pass months as an argument either you have to pass the `Date` or `No of Days`..

see this document for more info 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx

but instead you can read the value as months and convert it to days and pass it `forfiles` manually..

How are you passing days to forfile in your batchfile now?

Comment: I have mentioned the number of days directly in the batch file and just running the batch file in the task schedular

Comment: if you are specifying it directly in the batch file and not as an argument then you can directly specify 180 days why you need to convert it .. if you were going to pass it as argument then you might need to consider converting and the assigning it..