# how to delete files three months older than today using batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder in which log files are generated daily. I want to delete files which are 3 month older than today using batch file. I have seen many example but that are related to days but not months.I also checked this link 
[Delete files older than 6 months with batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31933907/delete-files-older-than-6-months-with-batch-file)

but it does not help me.
Can anyone help me how this task can be done.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does not help me. Why? Need more explanation!

Comment: @geisterfurz007 because i do not want to use powershell .. i want to solve my issue by using batch file.

Comment: After my understanding the command in the question stated in the link works but the OP wants to pass months. So you should be able to pass `90` days with `/d` and you should be fine. Although that is not including things like changing lengths and leap years it might be as close as you might get. You could definitely check for leapyears, length of each month as well but that is someting I personally would not do.

Comment: And on a side-note: You can run a powershell command from batch as well in a similar manner as you can run `cmd /c "commandHere"`.

Comment: actually i want this process to be automated like batch file takes current date i.e 9/26/2017 and then calculate 3 months older date i.e 6/26/2017 and then deleted all files which were created before 6/26/2017. If i do /d 90 then there would be some difference of days.

Comment: You really don't want to brute force date math in batch. A lot easier to call out to powershell, vbscript or jscript to do the date math calculation. But in my humble opinion I would just use FORFILES with 91 days. Three months is always going to be a different amount of days every month when you get to the end of the month. What will be your business rule for the end of April when it is April 29th or 30th? February 29 only comes around once every 4 years and February 30th will never exist.